# How to set variables in .env on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I have a script like this:

```
const item = [
  companyid : 23,
  summaryid : 2
];

const url = process.env.urlLink;
```

And I want to set the `url` in `.env` like this:

```
urlLink = "https://example.com/print/index/companyid=" + item.companyid + "&summaryid=" + item.summaryid
```

When I `console.log(url)`, I want to get this value:

```
https://example.com/print/index/companyid=23&summaryid=2
```

But I always get this value instead:

```
https://example.com/print/index/companyid=" + item.companyid + "&summaryid=" + item.summaryid
```

How can I get the variable `item.companyid` and `item.summaryid`?

Comment: Hi, Do you have dotenv installed?

Comment: yes. i've been installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to keep the array that you have in your script, your .env file could look like this:

```
urlLink = "https://example.com/print/index/companyid="
PARAM = "&summaryid="
```

And then your script

```
console.log(process.env.urlLink + item.companyid + process.env.PARAM + item.summaryid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution but it works

on .env put

```
         companyid : 23
         summaryid : 2
         LINK = "https://example.com/print/index/companyid="
```

on your log put

```
         console.log(process.env.LINK + process.env.companyid + "&summaryid=" + process.env.summaryid)
```

Comment: yes but, the value of array item.company_id is dynamic...this get from the value of array.

Comment: What I saw is that the .env file is very literal, you can only store strings or numbers links or dates but when we are talking about access those it gets messy, if it's dynamic you can access the properties separately. rather than that I dont know sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

In .env file :

```
 companyid = 23
 summaryid = 2
 LINK = "https://example.com/print/index/companyid="
```

in js file:

```
 console.log(process.env.LINK + process.env.companyid + "&summaryid=" + process.env.summaryid)
```

output:

```
 https://example.com/print/index/companyid=23&summaryid=2
```